# Does the Planck limit on the probability density of wave functions have any measurable effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, probability

The probability density of wave functions is an inverse volume.
If the smallest measurable volume is the Planck volume defined with the Planck length using $V_{min}=l_{Pl}^3$, then there is a maximum
measurable probability density given by $1/V_{min}=l_{Pl}^{-3}$.

For example, the limit would imply that delta distributions/functions should not be used in calculations, but that they have a finite maximum value.
Does this yield any measurable effect?
For example, an effect on QED?

Is the probability measurement limit testable in any other way?
Does this huge limit have any measurable effects?
Is there some effect of this limit in quantum gravity or in black holes?

I performed about 12 searches with Google Scholar, but did not find anything about all this. Is there any publication on the topic?
Indirectly, the limit also prevents the existence of singularities and point particles. But the topic is not discussed.

P.S. (To the moderators) This question is about wave functions, about probability densities, and about measurements.

Comment: Your question might be superficially about wavefunctions, but it rests on the mistaken assumption that the Planck length/volumes represent "smallest" measurements. The duplicate deals with that assumption and that is why I linked it as a duplicate

Comment: I read this: https://www.fnal.gov/pub/today/archive/archive_2013/today13-11-01_NutshellReadMore.html and this http://backreaction.blogspot.com/2012/01/planck-length-as-minimal-length.html so I thought this is standard.

Comment: Note that both of these only make the claim that it is impossible *"to determine a position to a precision smaller than the Planck length"* (this is a claim about *measurement*!), not that smaller lengths somehow don't exist. You, however, want to infer that *"delta distributions do not exist"*, which is emphatically not a claim about measurement.

Comment: I changed everything so that "measurement" is clearly meant everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Does this yield any measurable effect? For example, an effect on QED?

The answer seems to be no. The ability to probe the Planck scale would be required. Experiments are far way from achieving this ability.

- Is the probability measurement limit testable in any other way? Does this huge limit have any measurable effects? Is there some effect of this limit in quantum gravity or in black holes?

The answer seems to be no. No measurable effect appears to exist. This is just a further limit in the group of Planck limits.

The probability density limit implies the lack of singularities, but this is no news. The other Planck limits already imply this.

Additional literature searches found no result.

Answer (score -1):

> If the smallest measurable volume is the Planck volume defined with the Planck length using $V_{min}=l^3_{P_l}$, then there is a maximum measurable probability density given by $\frac {1}{V_{min}} = l^{−3}_{P_l}$.

No. The measured probability density remains constant. As the measured volume decreases, the probability of finding a particle in that volume is also decreasing proportionally.

Comment: I meant that the probability cannot be higher than the maximum value. Naively, it seems that it can be infinite, if the particle is localized at a point. The limit says that it cannot.

Comment: I believe what will happen is that at $V_{min}$  each measurement will either show one particle or nothing at that volume. Like a coin flip where $P_{heads} \neq P_{tails}$